# Close icon on modal stopped working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, modal-dialog

the close button on the upper left corner of the modal is not working 
here is my code.I have been trying to find the problem but i just cant find the problem
I tried running it from scratch but that didnt help too,

the close button on the upper left corner of the modal is not working 
here is my code.I have been trying to find the problem but i just cant find the problem
I tried running it from scratch but that didnt help too,

```html
<style>
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
    -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
    animation-name: animatetop;
    animation-duration: 0.4s
}

/* Add Animation */
@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
    from {top:-300px; opacity:0} 
    to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

@keyframes animatetop {
    from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
    to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: white;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-header {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    background-color: #5cb85c;
    color: white;
}

.modal-body {padding: 2px 16px;}

.modal-footer {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    background-color: #5cb85c;
    color: white;
}
.vege {
float: left;
width: 50%;
}
</style>



<h2>Animated Modal with Header and Footer</h2>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<div class="vege" id="myBtn"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1726/2025/files/final-1.jpg?12075096900285349117" <div="">

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">×</span>
      <h2>Modal Header</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
      <p>Some other text...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>



</div>
```

Comment: Show your HTML code and JavaScript code if it is there any.

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay did you scrolled the snippet?

Comment: @SagarV, sorry, my bad.!!! taking back my comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have added an eventListener to the close button and another to window.

When you click on the span, both event callbacks will execute. You have to prevent it by using `e.stopPropagation()` inside the callback of click event handler of span.

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
/* The Modal (background) */

.modal {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px;
  /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}


/* Modal Content */

.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-name: animatetop;
  animation-duration: 0.4s
}


/* Add Animation */

@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
  from {
    top: -300px;
    opacity: 0
  }
  to {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@keyframes animatetop {
  from {
    top: -300px;
    opacity: 0
  }
  to {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1
  }
}


/* The Close Button */

.close {
  color: white;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-header {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  background-color: #5cb85c;
  color: white;
}

.modal-body {
  padding: 2px 16px;
}

.modal-footer {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  background-color: #5cb85c;
  color: white;
}

.vege {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<h2>Animated Modal with Header and Footer</h2>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<div class="vege" id="myBtn"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1726/2025/files/final-1.jpg?12075096900285349117" <div="">

  <!-- The Modal -->
  <div id="myModal" class="modal">

    <!-- Modal content -->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <span class="close">×</span>
        <h2>Modal Header</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
        <p>Some other text...</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>




</div>
```

Comment: I need your Help http://liveweave.com/#&togetherjs=B2TcxhtHrl                 close span on second model not working

Comment: Hi @devdreamer you have an issue here `var gpan = document.getElementsByClassName("close2")` you're missing the index. It should be `var gpan = document.getElementsByClassName("close2")[0]`. I tried and works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

Try this :-

I have changed it little bit. 
Changes :-

1). Given Id to Span Tag

2). Changed code in JS regarding Span

3). Closed Div and Img tags in html properly.

4). Added class (.modal-backdrop) in css file

```js
    // Get the modal
    var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

    // Get the button that opens the modal
    var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

    // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
    var span = document.getElementById("CloseModal");

    // When the user clicks the button, open the modal
    btn.onclick = function () {
        modal.style.display = "block";
    }

    // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
    span.onclick = function () {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }

    // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
    window.onclick = function (event) {
        if (event.target == modal) {
            modal.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
```

```css
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
    -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
    animation-name: animatetop;
    animation-duration: 0.4s
}

/* Add Animation */
@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
    from {top:-300px; opacity:0} 
    to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

@keyframes animatetop {
    from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
    to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: white;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-header {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    background-color: #5cb85c;
    color: white;
}

.modal-body {padding: 2px 16px;}

.modal-footer {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    background-color: #5cb85c;
    color: white;
}
.vege {
float: left;
width: 50%;
}

.modal-backdrop {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1030;
}
```

```html
 <h2>Animated Modal with Header and Footer</h2>

    <!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
    <div class="vege" id="myBtn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
        <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1726/2025/files/final-1.jpg?12075096900285349117" />
    </div>

    <!-- The Modal -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
        <!-- Modal content -->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <span id="CloseModal" class="close">×</span>
                <h2>Modal Header</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
                <p>Some other text...</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Didn't work Archana if you could make it work any other way it would be highly appreciated

Comment: Hey @devdreamer , I have update my answer . Please try that.